# Derivative of Inverse Differential in Proof of Inverse Function Theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, inverse-function-theorem

On p. $194$ of *Mathematical Analysis* by Andrew Browder he defines a map $\psi: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ by
$$\psi(\mathbf{y})=d\mathbf{f}^{-1}_{\mathbf{p}}(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{q})$$
as a tool to prove the inverse function theorem. He then claims that
$$\psi'(\mathbf{q})=[\mathbf{f}'(\mathbf{p})]^{-1},$$
where $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{p})=\mathbf{q}$. Why is this the case? Isn't $d\mathbf{f}^{-1}_{\mathbf{p}}$ a linear map, and therefore its derivative should just be itself? But where is the $\mathbf{q}$ on the right hand side of the equation? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, $\psi$ is an affine transformation (linear plus a constant), so at every point $y$, the derivative $D\psi_y$ is equal to the linear part of $\psi$, which in this case is just $(Df_p)^{-1}$. Since $D\psi_y=[Df_p]^{-1}$ is true for all $y$, it is in particular true when $y=q$, thus $D\psi_q=[Df_p]^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you! That clarifies a lot — I still get confused with differential notation pretty often. One question: why is the derivative of $d\mathbf{f}^{-1}_{\mathbf{p}}(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{q}) = d\mathbf{f}^{-1}_{\mathbf{p}}$? Where does the $(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{q})$ part actually "go"?

Comment: @AlexanderPope There’s two ways of looking at it. First, $[Df_p]^{-1}(y-q)=[Df_p]^{-1}(y)-[Df_p]^{-1}(q)$ due to linearity. The second term is a constant, so when differentiating it becomes zero. Hence, we only have $Df_p^{-1}$.

Comment: The second way of viewing things is via the chain rule. Write $g(y)=y-q=I(y)-q$, where $I$ is the identity map. So, $Dg_y=DI_y-0=I$ (the zero is because we’re differentiating a constant $q$, and $DI_y=I$ because $I$ is a linear map so at every point it is it own derivative). Now, $\psi(y)=\left([Df_p]^{-1}\circ g\right)(y)$. So, by the chain rule, $D\psi_y=D\bigg([Df_p]^{-1}\bigg)_{g(y)}\circ Dg_y=\bigg([Df_p]^{-1}\bigg)\circ I=[Df_p]^{-1}$ based on what we said.

Comment: So, the $(y-q)$ part actually goes to the point of evaluation of the derivative of $[Df_p]^{-1}$, but since we’re differentiating a linear map, ‘the point of evaluation is not important. But, if for example you had a more complicated function like $\psi(y)=\phi(y-q)$, where $\phi$ is merely differentiable (not necessarily linear), then by the chain rule and “sum rule”, we have  $D\psi_y=D\phi_{y-q}\circ (DI_y-0)=D\phi_{y-q}$. So, that’s where the $(y-q)$ “goes”. But for now, I think my first comment will provide you the most direct answer.

Comment: Thank you again, @peek-a-boo. So in other words the derivative of $d\mathbf{f}^{-1}_{\mathbf{p}}(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{q})$  is actually $ d\mathbf{f}^{-1}_{\mathbf{p}}(\mathbf{y})$ However, we omit the $\mathbf{y}$ as the point of evaluation is irrelevant?

Comment: Be careful; your ‘in other words’ is changing the meaning. $[Df_p]^{-1}(y)$ is a vector, not a linear transformation. Re-read my comments to understand what I’m saying (this can be a little confusing initially, but spend some time on it). I’ve already expressed everything precisely above.

Comment: OK, I think I got it, many thanks!